# Create generic StepArgumentTransformations method

Tags: c#, generics, specflow

I want to write generic StepArgumentTransformation method.
Currently I have to add up several methods which works fine but I want to make that generic.

for example:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> EmployeeModel_Transform(Table table)
{   
    return table.CreateSet<EmployeeModel>();
}

[StepArgumentTransformation]
public IEnumerable<DepartmentModel> DepartmentModel_Transform(Table table)
{
    return table.CreateSet<DepartmentModel>();
}
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Generic step argument transformations, eg.

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public IEnumerable<T> Entity_Transform<T>(Table table)
{
    return table.CreateSet<T>();
}
```

are **currently not supported**. (Pull requests are welcome for this...)

If you have really a lot of these, I would suggest creating a small runtime plugin and provide a custom implementation of the `IStepArgumentTypeConverter` interface (handle the special transformation and delegate back the behavior to the `StepArgumentTypeConverter` for the others.)

Comment: Gaspar Nagy, please implement this feature, our team also needs it.